# How can you setup multisite(using subdirectories) making it so that other subdirectories are in the same top-level folder the primary site is in?

Tags: wordpress

How can you setup `multisite` (using sub-directories) making it so that other sub-directories are in the same top-level folder the primary site is in?

**Basic setup**

Basic setup is like this: `example.com/example`. This is the primary site of the `multisite` network I've created.

**Structure** with `multisite`

Note: `example.com` is not the MAIN page. The Wordpress is installed in a subfolder (`/site1`)

```
MAIN: /site1
  |- SUB: /site2
  |- SUB: /site3
```

**Problem**

URL for `/site2` is `example.com/site1/site2`

**Desired Output**

URL for `/site2` is `example.com/site2`

**Question**

*Is there a good way to do this? I've done some research but I haven't found anything that worked: so please explain step by step.*

Comment: What I want to do is: other sites created via multisite need to not be placed under the main subdirectory: so example.com/site1, example.com/site2, (but example.com/site1 is the MAIN site, example.com is not! So instead of example.com/site1/site2, example.com/site1/site3, etc. I want example.com/site1, example.com/site2, etc)

Comment: I ordered the text and made it easier to read, furthermore I've added information from the comment.

Answer (score 0):

Hi if i understand you question right, you need this:

1 Choose WordPress Multisite Mode

2 Update wp-config.php for using sub-directores

vim /var/www/example.com/htdocs/wp-config.php

```
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', false);
$base = '/';
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'example.com');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
```

3 Nginx Configuration for WordPress-Multisite with Subdirectories in a subdirectory

```
 server {
    server_name example.com ;

    access_log   /var/log/nginx/example.com.access.log;
    error_log    /var/log/nginx/example.com.error.log debug;

    root /var/www/example.com/htdocs ;
    index index.php;

    if (!-e $request_filename) {
            rewrite /wp-admin$ $scheme://$host$uri/ permanent;         
            rewrite ^/wordpress(/[^/]+)?(/wp-.*) /wordpress$2 last;      
            rewrite ^/wordpress(/[^/]+)?(/.*\.php)$ /wordpress$2 last;
    }

    location / {
            try_files $uri $uri/ /wordpress/index.php?$args ;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
            try_files $uri /wordpress/index.php;
            include fastcgi_params;
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
    }

    location ~* ^.+\.(ogg|ogv|svg|svgz|eot|otf|woff|mp4|ttf|rss|atom|jpg|jpeg|gif|png|ico|zip|tgz|gz|rar|bz2|doc|xls|exe|ppt|tar|mid|midi|wav|bmp|rtf)$ {
            access_log off; log_not_found off; expires max;
    }

    location = /robots.txt { access_log off; log_not_found off; }
    location ~ /\. { deny  all; access_log off; log_not_found off; }
```

Comment: Sorry that's not what I ment! I mean: I have wordpress installed in a subdirectory. What I want to do is: other sites created via multisite need to not be placed under the main subdirectory: so example.com/site1, example.com/site2, (but example.com/site1 is the MAIN site, example.com is not! So instead of example.com/site1/site2, example.com/site1/site3, etc. I want example.com/site1, example.com/site2, etc)